# Solace .NET CreateFlow with HandleMessageEvent null

Tags: .net, solace

I would like to create a flow and instead of using the `messageEventHandler` delegate I would like to have the messages be queued internally and call them by using `ReceiveMsg(Int32)`.

However when I pass null into the `CreateFlow` method for `messageEventHandler`, I receive the [attached error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKtQF.png).

All in all, I would like to be able to get the message at the specific times and not whenever the delegate gets triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the `messageEventHandler` delegate. The Solace .NET API only provides asynchronous callbacks for received messages.

As an alternative, you could have your application temporary store the received messages in an internal buffer, and only read and acknowledge them when ready. 
`FlowProperties.MaxUnackedMessages` and `FlowProperties.WindowSize` should also be set to a small value (such as 1) to prevent the buffer from overflowing.